# Prime divisors of $f(n):=F_{n^2}+F_n+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers, prime-factorization

Let $F_n$ be the $n$ th fibonacci-number and define $$f(n):=F_{n^2}+F_n+1$$

> For which positive integers $n$ do we have no small prime factor (say $p<10^7$) $p\mid f(n)$ ? Are there useful criterions for those $n$ ?

$f(n)$ is prime for $n=1,2,3,4,10$ and no other $n\le 700$

We have no prime factor below $10^7$ for the following positive integers ($10$ is excluded) : $[21, 26, 27, 32, 50, 51, 52, 60, 66, 92, 93, 98, 106, 120, 132, 146, 171, 180, 204, 218, 219, 220, 258, 290, 291, 292, 309, 412, 424, 429, 450, 460, 464, 472, 492, 500, 506, 532, 540, 544, 549, 552, 570, 584, 610, 650, 651, 660, 666, 693, 699, 700]$

The first case where factordb knows no prime factor is $n=92$.

[factordb](http://factordb.com/index.php?query=I%28n%5E2%29%2BI%28n%29%2B1&use=n&n=1&VP=on&VC=on&EV=on&OD=on&PRP=on&U=on&C=on&perpage=20&format=1&sent=Show)

Comment: Fibonacci, not "fiboncci" :)